# Tile movement every number of seconds

Tags: java, slick2d

I have this update method shown below:

```
@Override
public void update(Input input, int delta) {

    /* if UP, move player 5 tiles upwards */
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_UP) {
        y -= 5;
        setY(y);
    }

    /* if DOWN, move player 5 tiles downwards */
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_DOWN) {
        y += 5;
        setY(y);
    }

    /* if LEFT, move player 5 tiles to the left */
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_LEFT) {
        x -= 5;
        setX(x);
    }

    /* if RIGHT, move player 5 tiles to the right */
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_RIGHT) {
        x += 5;
        setX(x);  
    }
}
```

My update loop from my World class:

```
public void update(Input input, int delta) 
throws SlickException {

    // Update every sprite eg. Player, Blocks etc.
    for (Sprite sprite : list) {
        sprite.update(input, delta);
    }  
}
```

Where `setX()` and `setY()` are just setters from my class, which handle how many pixels the player should move in terms of tiles. Where each tile is 32 pixels.

So far this moves my player from one location to another location 5 tiles down, up, left or right. I was wondering if their was a way to make the player move one tile every 0.25 seconds to its destination? As in, every 0.25 seconds, the player would move 32 pixels in the left, right, down or up direction. I want this to be added so it looks like the player is sliding across tiles instead of teleporting straight to its location.

How could I use a timer to achieve this? Could I use delta to do this? Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a variable outside of the update loop that contains a timestamp.

int lastTimestamp;

Now, in your loop, make a conditional that checks if 250 milliseconds has passed since the time in *lastTimetamp*.

```
// Use System.nanoTime() / 1000000L to get current time
if(currentTime >= (lastTimestamp + 250)) {
   movePlayer();
   lastTimestamp = currentTime;
}
```

Now this condition should pass every 0.25 seconds.

Comment: You should not use Java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() because it is framerate dependent and might invoke different behaviors on different machines. I suggest you should use deltas.

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad right, so use System.nanoTime() then. My answer should still be valid.

Comment: Yes, but it's not good. Slick2D wants you to use the delta, that's why the developer build it in, why would you not use it? Furthermore System.nanoTime() is not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer:

[Java slick2d moving an object every x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396938/java-slick2d-moving-an-object-every-x-seconds)

You should definitly use delta for this since you want [framerate independent motion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/what-is-framerate-independent-motion) in your game.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a Runnable class MoveAnimation that you give to a 
ScheduledExecutorService.

```
class MoveAnimation { // the full player movement
    public boolean animationFinished();
    public void animate() {
        if (animationFinished()) {
            throw new Exception(); // there is probably a cleaner way to remove this from the executor
        }
    }
}

class AnimationControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService animationSchedule = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public void addMovement(MoveAnimation animation) {
        animationSchedule.scheduleAtFixedRate(animation::animate, 0, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

// in the event listener
if (input.keyIsPressed(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
    animationControl.addMovement(new MoveLeftAnimation(from, to));
}
```